# Focus is running before the click/change of a radio button. Is it possible to run the click/change before the focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, onfocus

Below you will see the code I am working on and an included JSFiddle.

**Issue:**

1. The focus is running before the click/change so the margin is moving before the radio button can be selected.

Please explain the code so I can learn from this. If you do not have a solution any hints or direction would also be helpful.

http://jsfiddle.net/nLgqhqwc/6/

***HTML***

```
<div class="panel">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>

<div class="panel">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>

<div class="panel">
    <select>
        <option>option</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="panel">
    <input type="radio"/>
</div>

<div class="panel">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.panel{
    padding:15px;
    background:grey;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

.panel-primary{
    margin:0 15px 0 15px;
    background:blue;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

***jQuery***

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.panel').click(function () {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.panel').removeClass('panel-primary');
        $(this).addClass('panel-primary');
    });

    $('input, select').bind('focus blur', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.panel').removeClass('panel-primary');
        $(this).closest(".panel").addClass('panel-primary');
    });
    
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.panel').removeClass('panel-primary mrgn-lft-lg');
        $(this).closest(".panel").addClass('panel-primary');
    });
    
});
```

Comment: Why don't you make the effect on `hover` instead of `focus`? You would not need jquery, because pure css will be enough. Just replace `.panel-primary` in your css with `.panel:hover`.

Comment: Needs to work using the TAB key.

Comment: OK, I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/nLgqhqwc/10/  See the fiddle and tell us if it works as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can just fire the event when the user goes over the `.panel`. To do this you have to replace the click:

```
$('.panel').click(function () {
```

with `click OR hover with the mouse`. That's the way:

```
$('.panel').on('click mouseover',function () {
```

And here is the example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nLgqhqwc/10/

**Another way**

When not focused, make the padding wider. This way the `.panel`'s content will not move (and the user can click it easily) and the margin will be still there:

```
.panel{
    padding:15px 30px;
}

.panel-primary {
    margin:0 15px 0 15px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/nLgqhqwc/11/

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a solution that works with only click not mouseover and click. Really appreciate the help though :)

Comment: Great idea but I am afraid it needs to be done with a margin and the radio/checkbox inputs will need to move.

Comment: It works yes but I am looking for a javascript solution and not a change to the way the page is presented to the user. More of a behind the scenes solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must listen the click event on capturing phase. You can do:

`document.querySelector('.panel').addEventListener('click', doSomething, true);`

Take a look [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) to understand the difference of capturing and bubbling phases.

The main problem is you won't use jQuery.

> Not all browsers support event capturing (for example, Internet
>   Explorer versions less than 9 don't) but all do support event
>   bubbling, which is why it is the phase used to bind handlers to events
>   in all cross-browser abstractions, jQuery's included.
>   [jQuery equivalent of JavaScript's addEventListener method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398099/jquery-equivalent-of-javascripts-addeventlistener-method)

Therefore, you shouldn't concern about event order. You may resolve [simple](http://jsfiddle.net/nLgqhqwc/12/).

Comment: Thanks for replying. In the example you provided the class is not added when I tab to the radio buttons.